# How can i transfer a file or files from a bucket to the file system of a GCE instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, bucket, google-compute-engine

The documentation says download it, but when i try downloading, it downloads back to my local workstation. Is there a way to just transfer it within the cloud?

Comment: By the way what documentation are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

To download a file from GCS bucket to an instance:

- SSH to instance (using `gcloud ssh` command or clicking on `SSH` button on the instances page in console.cloud.google.com).
- Issue command `gsutil cp gs://$BUCKET/$file .